# Setup Apache + mod_wsgi: incorrect function

Tags: apache-2.2, mod-wsgi, windows-8

I'm trying to setup an apache http server with mod_wsgi on a windows machine, but when I start the service, it fails to launch.

In the Windows Event Log I get the following message:

```
The Apache2 service terminated with the following service-specific error: 
Incorrect function.
```

In running a Windows 8 - 64 bits machine, with

- Apache 2.0.64 32 bits
- Python 2.7.8 32 bits
- mod_wsgi 3.5 32 bits

I looked around the web, but all the problem but everywhere says that it's a problem with the architecture of the software, but I already installed them all with the 32 bits version.

Comment: Why are you using such an ancient Apache version? It is unlikely there are downloadable binaries for mod_wsgi for Apache 2.0 around, so not sure where you sourced it from. Use binaries from http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/ and the Apache version referenced from there. Use 64 bits for everything is preferred, so uninstall and start over.

Comment: I used 2.0 because someone had managed to install the environment with that version. Switched all to the most recent 64bits versions and it worked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Managed to solve the problem by installing all with 64 bits version.

Answer (score 0):

I am running `wampserver` in a 64 bit version (`wampserver64`), and apache 2.4.9 in a 64 bit version as well (`wampapache64`), and I downloaded `mod_wsgi-3.5.ap24.win-amd64-py2.7` from [**here**](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#mod_wsgi) (*I had to use Firefox to download as Chrome refused for some odd reason*).

Even though I did all this I still got an "*incorrect function*" when starting Apache.

The solution is to install Python in a 64 bit version (my python version was 32 bit) and then start the service.